# c++ builder Excel Ole Create new worksheet after the last sheet

Tags: c++, excel, c++builder, ole

I want to add a new worksheet not at the beginning but at the end of the worksheet tabs. But i can only manage to get it working at the front.

```
workSheet = workSheets.OleFunction("Add");
```

How can i change this line of code to make it add at the end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Worksheets.Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.add) method has optional `Before` and `After` parameters:

> Before
>   An object that specifies the sheet before which the new sheet is added.
>
> After
>   An object that specifies the sheet after which the new sheet is added.
>
> ...
>
> If `Before` and `After` are both omitted, **the new sheet is inserted before the active sheet**.

Comment: And how can i only add after because if i make the line look like workSheets.OleFunction("Add",NULL,variantAfter) I get a error message

Comment: Use `OleVariant::NoParam()` instead of NULL. Also see [How pass optional parameters to OLE method](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=269570)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set After param

```
Excel::_WorksheetPtr newSheet;
if (const auto sheetsCount = m_book->Worksheets->GetCount(); sheetsCount == 0)
    newSheet = m_app->Worksheets->Add();
else
{
    IDispatchPtr dispatch = m_app->Worksheets->GetItem(sheetsCount); // Number of sheet, not index
    newSheet = m_app->Worksheets->Add(vtMissing, dispatch.GetInterfacePtr(), 1);
}
return newSheet;
```